# How to go back in jquery mobile without triggering the animation?

Tags: jquery-mobile, back

Going *back* in jquery mobile will trigger a `$.mobile.changePage()` with the `location.hash` as explained in the jquery mobile docs.

I wan't to be able to do a `history.go(-N)` without anything happening except the history of the browser being shortened by the last N elements.

So I wish to avoid the animation of `$.mobile.changePage()` that will hide and show a different page.

Is it possible ?, and how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I did, but I'm not happy at all with it. But it does the trick.

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
history.go(-history_steps);
...

setTimeout(function() {
   $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = true;
}, 300);
```

The timeout is here to try to re-enable the normal behavior **after** the real `hashchange` event is triggered.

I would be really happy if someone could have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is "rel=external" function in jQueryMobile and it won't trigger the animation.

Comment: well this doesn't help me going back in browser history. Or I didn't catch it.

Comment: <a href="javascript:history.back()" data-icon="back" data-role="button" rel="external">Back</a> Try this one.