# Is it possible to go back to specified page id in jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Suppose I have 4 pages with this page IDs:

> pageA -> pageB -> pageC -> pageD

There can be an event in `pageC` and `pageD` that can make the application go back to `pageB`, the problem is that depending on the page I'm currently at I should call `history.go(-N)` where `N` is the number of pages that I should go back. For example if I am in `pageD` I should call `history.go(-2)`, in case of `pageC` `history.go(-1)` to keep history consistently. How would you do that in jQuery Mobile so that history would contain:

> pageA -> pageB

Another solution would be just to navigate to `pageB` directly with `$("body").pagecontainer("change", "pageB.html")` the problem with that is that the history chain would be wrong like this:

> pageA -> pageB -> pageC -> pageD -> pageB

All pages have a back button that's why it is important to keep history chain consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.mobile.activePage.attr('id')` to determine what page you're on then you can back up to the page you want having determined how many steps back you should go. Let me know if this is workable.

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866757/) useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the changeHash option to stop jQM from adding a history item:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change

```
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "pageB.html", {changeHash: false});
```

Comment: But I want to have the ability to go back because all pages have a BACK button. If I understand correctly, this will make it impossible to use back functionality.

Comment: You can use it selectively for only the changes you don't want in history. Did I not understand your question perhaps?